# Universal object of sealed class

Tags: generics, kotlin

I have `State` sealed class which represents the state of loading some resources. I would like to have a `Loading` object of this class. I tried to write it like this but it doesn't work:

```
sealed class State<T> {
    object Loading : State<Nothing>()
    data class Result<T>(val data: List<T>) : State<T>()
}

val t: State<String> = State.Loading
```

I know that I can use `Loading` class like that:

```
sealed class State<T> {
    class Loading<T> : State<T>()
    data class Result<T>(val data: List<T>) : State<T>()
}
```

But maybe there is a way to make it works with single `object`?

Comment: write `sealed class State<out T>`

Comment: Replace `sealed class State<T>` with `sealed class State<out T>`.

Comment: thank you, guys! It really works!